# Function and meaning of parameter lat_0 in Transverse Mercator Projection in PROJ String

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, pyproj

One may specify a custom Transverse Mercator in PROJ library string with something like:

```
proj +proj=tmerc +lat_0=-25 +lon_0=-49
```

For me the function of the parameter `lon_0` is clear, is the Central Meridian, and as a Cartographer it's the only one that makes sense for me.

But what the `lat_0` does? For the equator is the only the maximum circle with radius as the semiaxis `a`, there's no way to generate a Transverse and Tangent projection in another parallel... or there is? Or this parameter generates an Oblique Mercator (but there's a specific documentation for this case)?

the [documentation](https://proj.org/operations/projections/tmerc.html) only says:

> +lat_0=value
>
> > Latitude of projection center.

Comment: Documentation and formulas are here http://geotiff.maptools.org/proj_list/transverse_mercator.html but I can't really interpret them. You can experiment the effect by changing the lat_0 value for example with gdaltransform. Here a modified EPSG:5664 `gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:4326 -t_srs "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=30 +lon_0=9 +k=1 +x_0=2500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=krass +towgs84=24,-123,-94,0.02,-0.25,-0.13,1.1 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs"`.

Comment: So it may just be the Latitude to put the plane X axis, before summing up False E and  False N? I am not really good at looking to complex formulae, but at the "Projection Parameters" table, the OGC column makes an important distincion: "lon_0" is central meridian and "lat_0" is just latitude of origin.